# How to find out the valid values to use for authorized grant types in Spring Secrity

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I want to allow a client to use a specific grant type, but cannot find the valid values to use in the client table in the documentation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very good question - I struggled to find the values for hours.

Here is how to gather the different values. Every implementation of `AbstractTokenGranter` carries static field grant type `GRANT_TYPE`:

- `refresh_token` - RefreshTokenGranter
- `authorization_code` - AuthorizationCodeTokenGranter
- `implicit` - ImplicitTokenGranter
- `password` - ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter
- `client_credentials` - ClientCredentialsTokenGranter

The authorized grant types of a client can be found in the client instance via `ClientDetails.getAuthorizedGrantTypes`

And last but not least spring security oauth follows the specification here - so the grant types mentioned above match those mentioned in the spec.

Comment: I'm surprised I can't find any constants that correspond to the few set of OAuth grant types (ie CLIENT_CREDENTIALS, AUTH_CODE, etc)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/JonasGroeger/d32b6e67e6ee38465c4dab44fa7a2486) is something I use regularly:

```
public enum OAuth2GrantTypes {

    AUTHORIZATION_CODE("authorization_code"),
    IMPLICIT("implicit"),
    PASSWORD("password"),
    CLIENT_CREDENTIALS("client_credentials"),
    REFRESH_TOKEN("refresh_token");

    // Currently not supported by Spring Security
    // https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-device-flow-01
    // DEVICE_CODE("device_code")

    private final String name;

    OAuth2GrantTypes(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This allows you to specify the grant types like this:

```
.authorizedGrantTypes(
    OAuth2GrantTypes.IMPLICIT.getName()
)
```